# When I die, a heart doesn't get removed, but no errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a 2d runner and i have this "collision.cs" file that I have my heart system in, I don't get any errors but when I die a heart doesn't get removed so what am I doing wrong?

The system is based on tags so I tried changing the tag system a lot but nothing worked; then I tried to change the way I find the gameobject after a while I saw that it was creating a lot off gameobjects instead of 3 so I tried to change the tag system around that but even that didn't work and I really don't want to have a plain text that says 3 lives etc.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

    public class Collision : MonoBehaviour {

        public int lifes = 3    ;
        //public GameObject Life_icon1;
        //public GameObject Life_icon2;
        //public GameObject Life_icon3;
        public  Sprite Heart;
        public  int current_icon = 3;
        public  GameObject ParentPanel; 

        public static int Coins = 0;

        public  float offset = 150f;
        List<int> i = new List<int>() { 1 };

        public int tagN;

        void Update() {
            tagN = i.Max() + 1;
        }

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {
        for(int x = 0; x < lifes; x++)
        {
            i.Add(x);
            GameObject NewObj = new GameObject(); //Create the GameObject
            Image NewImage = NewObj.AddComponent<Image>(); //Add the Image Component script
            NewImage.gameObject.tag = x.ToString();
            if(x == 0) {
                NewImage.transform.position = new Vector3(0 + 40f, 0 + 40f , 0);
            } else {
                NewImage.transform.position = new Vector3(0 + offset, 0 + 40f , 0);
                offset += 130f;
            }
            //print(x);
            NewImage.sprite = Heart; //Set the Sprite of the Image Component on the new GameObject
            NewObj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().SetParent(ParentPanel.transform); //Assign the newly created Image GameObject as a Child of the Parent Panel.
            NewObj.SetActive(true); //Activate the GameObject
        }
        }

         void AddLife(int amount) {
            lifes++;
            i.Add(amount);
            GameObject NewObj = new GameObject(); //Create the GameObject
            NewObj.gameObject.tag = tagN.ToString();
            Image NewImage = NewObj.AddComponent<Image>(); //Add the Image Component script
            NewImage.transform.position = new Vector3(0 + offset, 0 + 40f , 0);
            NewImage.sprite = Heart; //Set the Sprite of the Image Component on the new GameObject
            NewObj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().SetParent(ParentPanel.transform); //Assign the newly created Image GameObject as a Child of the Parent Panel.
            NewObj.SetActive(true); //Activate the GameObject
        }


        void DelLife(int amount) {
            Vector3 pos = transform.position;


            offset -= 130f;

            pos.x = -0.49f;
            pos.y = -0.49f;
            transform.position = pos;

            i.RemoveAt(i.Max());

                 GameObject go = null;
                 if (GameObject.FindWithTag(tagN.ToString()) != null)
                 {
                     go = GameObject.FindWithTag(tagN.ToString());
                 }
                 if (go != null)
                 {
                     go.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                 }

        }

        void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
            {          

                //extra life item collision
                if(other.gameObject.name == "Heart_item") {
                        AddLife(1);
                        Destroy(other.gameObject);
                }

                if(other.gameObject.name == "Spike") {
                        DelLife(1);
                    }   

                    if(other.gameObject.name == "Coin") {
                        Destroy(other.gameObject);
                        Coins += 1;
                    }

          }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see you attaching a collider to the game objects that should participate in a collision. No collider, no collisions, i suppose. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html

Comment: i have a rigidbody to all my spikes and a collider that is set on trigger so can u explain a bit more :) i am kinda new at this

Comment: You are not checking the tags, you are checking the name

Comment: but the tag thing is only for finding the hearts not for actually when i collide with one i understand if u are confused with the "heart_item" it adds a heart not deletes or anything else

Comment: why not change `GameObject go = null;` to `go = GameObject.FindWithTag(tagN.ToString());`  that first if check is kinda pointless tbh in `DelLife`

Comment: Shouldn't you be subtracting 1 from `lifes` when you lose a life?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway i dont think thats the issue because he isnt even using `lifes` in his removal, but he is never updating tagN either...